# Firefox not loading websites through Selenium proxy

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, proxy, selenium-firefoxdriver

When I start a Selenium test a proxy is started successfully:

```
DefaultHttpProxyServer:448 - Starting proxy at address: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:0
DefaultHttpProxyServer:477 - Proxy listening with TCP transport
DefaultHttpProxyServer:512 - Proxy started at address: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:57982
```

Firefox is configured by Selenium to use this proxy. In the settings the proxy is set to my computer's name and to the port `57982`.

Unfortunately no connection to a website can be established. Neither one to a page on my local server, nor one to [google.com](http://google.com).

I'm using Selenium in the version `2.47.1` and Firefox in `41.0`. I'm using Windows 7.

What could be the problem? How can I narrow down the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I've messed up my `hosts` file and my computer's name pointed to an unreachable IP. I've removed that line and now Firefox is working with Selenium.